# Migration from JDK8 to JDK11 causing java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, collections, java-8, hashset, java-11

You you can see from the class name properties.stringPropertyNames() returns an Collections$UnmodifiableCollection. Unmodifiable means you can't add, insert, remove or change something on this collection

Comment: What is the instancied type of properties.stringPropertyNames()?

Comment: You you can see from the class name `properties.stringPropertyNames()` returns an `Collections$UnmodifiableCollection`. Unmodifiable means you can't add, insert, remove or change something on this collection.

Comment: the type of properties is Properties

Answer (score 11):

Now that you have explained what the type of `properties` is `java.util.Properties` the answer is clear.  In Java 8, `Properties.stringPropertyNames()` returned a set whose modifiability was unspecified:

> *"Returns a set of keys in this property list where the key and its corresponding value are strings, including distinct keys in the default property list if a key of the same name has not already been found from the main properties list. Properties whose key or value is not of type String are omitted."*
>
> *"The returned set is not backed by the Properties object. Changes to this Properties are not reflected in the set, or vice versa."*.

In Java 11, it is specified to be unmodifiable.

> *"Returns an unmodifiable set of keys from this property list where the key and its corresponding value are strings, including distinct keys in the default property list if a key of the same name has not already been found from the main properties list. Properties whose key or value is not of type String are omitted."*
>
> *"The returned set is not backed by this Properties object. Changes to this Properties object are not reflected in the returned set."*

The change happened in Java 9.  This is related to [bug 8059361](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8059361).

(This is was an incompatible change in the sense that it could break customers' code if they relied on being able to modify the returned set. However, that code was relying on unspecified behavior, so you could argue that it was broken already.)

Comment: In Java 8 `Properties.stringPropertyNames()` returned a modifiable collection. This was even mentioned in the JavaDoc (in detail it was stated that modifications to it have no effect on the Properties instance).

Comment: Yes you are right, i have edit the question and added full function in the code. Have a look

Comment: @Robert - that is a *hint* that the collection is modifiable, but an unmodifiable collection would have the same property.  (Think about it.)

Comment: @Robert Thank you make sense. Clear my point.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand correctly, you have unmodifiable set and you are tying to change it here

`parameterNames.removeIf(s -> !s.startsWith(seq));`

that's why you getting this error/exception.

```
Set<String> parameterNames = new HashSet<>(properties.stringPropertyNames());
```

This will create a new Set with same content which can be altered.

Comment: Yes you are right, i have edit the question and added full function in the code. Have a look

Comment: @MutahirKiani Hope you are clean with above post now.